# Need help calculating longitude and latitude midpoint using javascript from php values

Tags: php, javascript

I am currently working on a project and have run into quite a snag.
I am running a mapping application using the google maps API and I need to calculate the midpoint between two points, which are 4 total pts (lat/long) which are stored as php values from a user.

The formula I am currently using needs to convert my values which are in degrees, to radians.
And I then need to convert them back to degrees to plug into the google mapping portion of my code.

I need to calculate this point so i can display it as the middle of my map so that it will display neatly and centered.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<?php

$from = $_POST["from"];
$to = $_POST["to"];

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "dlazett", "PASSWORD");

mysql_select_db("dlazett", $connection);

$f = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM capstone WHERE id = '$from' ",
$connection);

$wfrom = mysql_fetch_array($f);

$latf = $wfrom["lat"];
$lonf = $wfrom["lon"];

$t = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM capstone WHERE id = '$to' ",
$connection);

$wto = mysql_fetch_array($t);

$latt = $wto["lat"];
$lont = $wto["lon"];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-…
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<title>UT Campus Compass</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=ap…
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function midpoint() {
var lat2 = (<?php echo "$latf";?>) * (Math.PI/180);
var lat1 = (<?php echo "$latt";?>) * (Math.PI/180);
var dLon = (<?php echo "$lonf";?>-<?php echo "$lont";?>) * (Math.PI/180);
var Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
var By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
var lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1)+Math.sin(lat2)…
Math.sqrt( (Math.cos(lat1)+Bx)*(Math.cos(lat1)+Bx) + By*By) );
var lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);
var lat4 = lat3 * (180/Math.PI);
var lon4 = lon3 * (180/Math.PI);
}

function initialize() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canva…
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat4, lon4), 16);
var polyline = new GPolyline([
new GLatLng(<?php echo "$latf";?>, <?php echo "$lonf";?>),
new GLatLng(<?php echo "$latt";?>, <?php echo "$lont";?>)
], "#ff0000", 10);
map.addOverlay(polyline);
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<center>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 425px; height: 600px"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere? What help do you need? I would write *degToRad* and *radToDeg* functions instead of writing the same code several times, but other than that, what do you want?

Answer (score 3):

in PHP

```
function midpoint ($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) {

    $lat1= deg2rad($lat1);
    $lng1= deg2rad($lng1);
    $lat2= deg2rad($lat2);
    $lng2= deg2rad($lng2);

    $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
    $Bx = cos($lat2) * cos($dlng);
    $By = cos($lat2) * sin($dlng);
    $lat3 = atan2( sin($lat1)+sin($lat2),
    sqrt((cos($lat1)+$Bx)*(cos($lat1)+$Bx) + $By*$By ));
    $lng3 = $lng1 + atan2($By, (cos($lat1) + $Bx));
    $pi = pi();
    return ($lat3*180)/$pi .' '. ($lng3*180)/$pi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) { 

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
  $dist = acos($dist); 
  $dist = rad2deg($dist); 
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344); 
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}
```

This function will help you

Comment: Can you add some level of description to explain how it will help?

Answer (score 0):

Use Openlayers and it helps to do this. http://www.openlayers.org/

Answer (score 0):

For a javascript version I converted @vineesh's answer.

```
function midpoint ($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) {
    $lat1 = $lat1 * 0.017453292519943295;
    $lng1 = $lng1 * 0.017453292519943295;
    $lat2 = $lat2 * 0.017453292519943295;
    $lng2 = $lng2 * 0.017453292519943295;

    $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
    $Bx = Math.cos($lat2) * Math.cos($dlng);
    $By = Math.cos($lat2) * Math.sin($dlng);
    $lat3 = Math.atan2( Math.sin($lat1)+Math.sin($lat2),
    Math.sqrt((Math.cos($lat1)+$Bx)*(Math.cos($lat1)+$Bx) + $By*$By ));
    $lng3 = $lng1 + Math.atan2($By, (Math.cos($lat1) + $Bx));
    $pi = 3.141592653589793;
    $lat = ($lat3*180)/$pi;
    $lng = ($lng3*180)/$pi;
    return [$lat,$lng];
}
```