# Calculate the mid point of latitude and longitude co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geo

Does anyone know the best way to go about getting the mid-point of a pair of latitude and longitude points?

I mm using d3.js to draw points on a map and need to draw a curved line between two points, so I need to create a mid point to draw a curve in the lines.

Please see image below for a better understanding of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Are you having a technical problem? Or do you just want help with the math?

Comment: @ColBeseder I would be grateful for some help with the math. I have no problem drawing the lines etc, the image provided is a working example but I had to hard-code the mid-points, which is not scalable as I have to draw many more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apologies for the long script - it just seemed fun to draw stuff :-). I've marked off sections that are not required

```
// your latitude / longitude
var co2 = [70, 48];
var co1 = [-70, -28];


// NOT REQUIRED
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

function drawPoint(color, point) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawCircle(point, r) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray';
    ctx.setLineDash([5, 5]);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}


// REQUIRED
// convert to cartesian
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()

var cot1 = projection(co1);
var cot2 = projection(co2);

var p0 = { x: cot1[0], y: cot1[1] };
var p1 = { x: cot2[0], y: cot2[1] };


// NOT REQUIRED
drawPoint('green', p0);
drawPoint('green', p1);


// REQUIRED
function dfn(p0, p1) {
    return Math.pow(Math.pow(p0.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p0.y - p1.y, 2), 0.5);
}

// from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/87374
var d = dfn(p0, p1);
var m = {
    x: (p0.x + p1.x) / 2,
    y: (p0.y + p1.y) / 2,
}

var u = (p1.x - p0.x) / d
var v = (p1.y - p0.y) / d;

// increase 1, if you want a larger curvature
var r = d * 1;
var h = Math.pow(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(d, 2) / 4, 0.5);

// 2 possible centers
var c1 = {
    x: m.x - h * v,
    y: m.y + h * u
}
var c2 = {
    x: m.x + h * v,
    y: m.y - h * u
}


// NOT REQUIRED
drawPoint('gray', c1)
drawPoint('gray', c2)

drawCircle(c1, r)
drawCircle(c2, r)


// REQUIRED

// from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/919423
function mfn(p0, p1, c) {
    // the -c1 is for moving the center to 0 and back again
    var mt1 = {
        x: r * (p0.x + p1.x - c.x * 2) / Math.pow(Math.pow(p0.x + p1.x - c.x * 2, 2) + Math.pow(p0.y + p1.y - c.y * 2, 2), 0.5)
    };
    mt1.y = (p0.y + p1.y - c.y * 2) / (p0.x + p1.x - c.x * 2) * mt1.x;

    var ma = {
        x: mt1.x + c.x,
        y: mt1.y + c.y,
    }

    var mb = {
        x: -mt1.x + c.x,
        y: -mt1.y + c.y,
    }

    return (dfn(ma, p0) < dfn(mb, p0)) ? ma : mb;
}

var m1 = mfn(p0, p1, c1);
var m2 = mfn(p0, p1, c2);

var mo1 = projection.invert([m1.x, m1.y]);
var mo2 = projection.invert([m2.x, m2.y]);


// NOT REQUIRED
drawPoint('blue', m1);
drawPoint('blue', m2);

// your final output (in lat long)
console.log(mo1);
console.log(mo2);
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/srjuc2gd/

---

[image]

---

And here's just the relevant portion (most of it is just copy-pasta from the beginning of this answer)

```
var Q31428016 = (function () {

    // adjust curvature
    var CURVATURE = 1;


    // project to convert from lat / long to cartesian
    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular();

    // distance between p0 and p1
    function dfn(p0, p1) {
        return Math.pow(Math.pow(p0.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p0.y - p1.y, 2), 0.5);
    }

    // mid point between p0 and p1
    function cfn(p0, p1) {
        return {
            x: (p0.x + p1.x) / 2,
            y: (p0.y + p1.y) / 2,
        }
    }

    // get arc midpoint given end points, center and radius - http://math.stackexchange.com/a/919423
    function mfn(p0, p1, c, r) {

        var m = cfn(p0, p1);

        // the -c1 is for moving the center to 0 and back again
        var mt1 = {
            x: r * (m.x - c.x) / Math.pow(Math.pow(m.x - c.x, 2) + Math.pow(m.y - c.y, 2), 0.5)
        };
        mt1.y = (m.y - c.y) / (m.x - c.x) * mt1.x;

        var ma = {
            x: mt1.x + c.x,
            y: mt1.y + c.y,
        }

        var mb = {
            x: -mt1.x + c.x,
            y: -mt1.y + c.y,
        }

        return (dfn(ma, p0) < dfn(mb, p0)) ? ma : mb;
    }

    var Q31428016 = {};
    Q31428016.convert = function (co1, co2) {

        // convert to cartesian
        var cot1 = projection(co1);
        var cot2 = projection(co2);

        var p0 = { x: cot1[0], y: cot1[1] };
        var p1 = { x: cot2[0], y: cot2[1] };


        // get center - http://math.stackexchange.com/a/87374
        var d = dfn(p0, p1);
        var m = cfn(p0, p1);

        var u = (p1.x - p0.x) / d
        var v = (p1.y - p0.y) / d;

        var r = d * CURVATURE;
        var h = Math.pow(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(d, 2) / 4, 0.5);

        // 2 possible centers
        var c1 = {
            x: m.x - h * v,
            y: m.y + h * u
        }
        var c2 = {
            x: m.x + h * v,
            y: m.y - h * u
        }


        // get arc midpoints
        var m1 = mfn(p0, p1, c1, r);
        var m2 = mfn(p0, p1, c2, r);


        // convert back to lat / long
        var mo1 = projection.invert([m1.x, m1.y]);
        var mo2 = projection.invert([m2.x, m2.y]);

        return [mo1, mo2]
    }

    return Q31428016;
})();


// your latitude / longitude
var co1 = [-70, -28];
var co2 = [70, 48];

var mo = Q31428016.convert(co1, co2)

// your output
console.log(mo[0]);
console.log(mo[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to go through all of the answers provided to make sure i choose the best one for my case. This looks spor on though. Can you provide a smaller code base with just the relevant parts for anyone else that comes across this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask if you can create a working + editable example (codepen/jsfiddle etc) for any other users that come across this answer. Adding this will give you answer a better chance of being the selected one as it wilkl allow for new visitors to play about with your implementation.

Comment: There's a Show Code snippet in the middle of the answer. That work? Here's a fiddle btw - https://jsfiddle.net/srjuc2gd/. I'd rather not bloat the answer :-), but feel free to edit it in if you feel it will improve the answer. cheers!

Comment: The "Show Snippet" part is not editable by users. That's great, you could probably stipr down you answer now too. Gtreat answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How could I alter this for cases where I need to draw multiple lines coming from multiple different points? For example, say I did not have 2 circles like in the image I added, but 10 instead, and I wanted to draw lines between them?

Comment: Like, how could I get this into a for loop to return on object of mid points instead of just the static 2 that are currently output > `console.log(mo1);
console.log(mo2);` Ideally, I would like to be able to return ,amy midpoints not just 2. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the latter part of my answer - just do `var mo = Q31428016.convert(co1, co2);` for each pair of points you want the midpoints for (also replaced the snippet with a fiddle!)

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'convert' of undefined` when I move your code to mine. Weird as it works fine in fiddle amd I am only moving it over without changung anything

Comment: The code in the fiddle appears to be the older version of your solution?

Comment: Sorry. yeah, the fiddle is the older one with the diagrams and all == the first block of code in the answer. The 2nd block of code in the answer is the minimal one - this is the one you should use.

Comment: Look at the end of the 2nd block. that's how you call it.

Comment: The seond block of code gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'convert' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83554/discussion-between-alan-and-potatopeelings).

Comment: Updated 2nd block of answer so that it works with "use strict"

Comment: Hi, I have a similar question that I would really appreciate you help with. It is about getting the angle of degree between the two points: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583441/how-to-calculate-angle-of-degree-between-two-points-to-ruse-as-a-rotate-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583441/how-to-calculate-angle-of-degree-between-two-points-to-ruse-as-a-rotate-value). Can you help?

Comment: How would I give the cruve the same size for each line, instead of setting it according to the distance beywenn two points?

Comment: `var r = Math.max(d / 2, <<your value>>);` instead of `var r = d * CURVATURE;` (and remove unused CURVATURE). The value needs to be little higher, otherwise, the circle won't be large enough to pass through both points (hence the lower limit of d/2. Btw, I see you already have an answer for your other question (in your comments there) - right?

Comment: I am just getting straight lines between the two pints when I use `var r = Math.max(d / 2, <<any value>>);` Maybe I phrased the request wrong. I meant I still wanted a curved line between the two points, I just to gap between the two midpoints to be the same for every set of liines. I also forgot to mention that I was referring to the the question I lined to you in the above comments

Comment: Er... bit confused. My comment was for how to ensure the same radius (curvature) irrespective of how far apart the points are, So effectively points that are close will have a gentle (compared to the distance between them) arc between them and points that are farther will have a visibly curved (w.r.t the distance between them) arc between them (but with the same radius as the gentle arc). https://jsfiddle.net/6v4sye0m/ - if you increase MYVALUE to a large enough value it will LOOK like a straight line (it's just a curve of a really large circle) - the fiddle has both implementations.

Comment: Rereading your comment. My bad!. So we're all done with this thread and we just want to sort out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428016?

Comment: No Matter what value I use for MYVALUE, i get straight lines overlapping each other between two points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84167/discussion-between-alan-and-potatopeelings).

Comment: I have another similar question again, this one requires to calculcate waypoint along great circle by percentagae of distance? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640252/get-latitude-and-longitude-points-along-a-line-between-two-points-by-percentage]

Answer (score 4):

**For the accurate side:**

You may use the Esri web API. Nothing beats decades of experience implementing the hard side of projection systems and datums... Athough the ArcGIS for Server line is a commercial product, the JS API is free, and here there's a pure JS function that does just what you want : [geometryEngine.densify](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#densify) ; that function requires an interval parameter, that you can, in your case, get by dividing by two the results of [geometryEngine.geodesicLength](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#geodesiclength)

That'll need you to get acquainted with the [Polyline](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/polyline-amd.html) class in a very basic way, such as `var mySegment = new Polyline([[50,3], [55,8]]);` and probably nothing further.

**For the visual side :**

Your segment has two middles ? You may also be interested in [geometryEngine.offset](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#offset) ; first offset the original segment once in each direction, then get the center point for each of the resulting segments.

**For the practical side :**

Given the short distances involved, provided you're not dealing with a weird place that'd be too close to the poles, I'd simply go with an arithmetic average of X and Y, and then add/subtract a rotated vector to offset your two "middles". Doing it this way would be both lighter on the machine (no libs to load from a CDN), easier on you, and as long as the purpose of it is a nice display, the result will be more than good enough.

(added as per comment : a sample)

```
// Your known starting points, and a k factor of your choice.
var a = {x:3, y:50};
var b = {x:8, y:55};
var k = 0.2;

// Intermediate values
var vab =       {x:b.x-a.x, y:b.y-a.y};
var v_rotated = {x:-k*vab.y, y:k*vab.x};
var middle =    {x:a.x+vab.x/2, y:a.y+vab.y/2};

// Your two resulting points
var result_i = {x: middle.x + v_rotated.x,  y: middle.y + v_rotated.y};
var result_j = {x: middle.x - v_rotated.x,  y: middle.y - v_rotated.y};
```

Comment: Do you have a snippett of code for the **For the practical side:**?

Comment: Sure. It's just your basic vector math, a bit obfuscated by Javacript's lack of vector operators. :) I insist that this will not yield a *geographically* sound point, hence the use of x and y instead of lon and lat, however it should look pretty good on a city / county map, and not be shocking on a UK map.

Comment: Thanks, let me go through the answers and choose the best one for my case. I will likely end up up-voting many answers as there have been so many great answers. SO community >

Comment: I'd guess the reason to be that, within the realm of recurrent JS questions we see around here, your question's title was promising a refreshing change. :D

Comment: Yes, you're probably correct. A lot of people tend to ask question without checking if the answer already exists. I did look around before posting. It's good that people like yourself get excited about answering a relatively un-asked question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, do you have a working example of this with d3 in a codepen/jsfiddle etc?

Comment: I only ask, as I would like the chosen answers to have working examlpes for further users to be able to reference.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with d3 and have no time for it right now. :) All you get here is the working example with resulting points that'll be located where you want your arrows to be. But I leave it up to you to plot them with d3.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657194/need-help-calculating-longitude-and-latitude-midpoint-using-javascript-from-php) question, you can use it to find the middle of your coordination on google map. I customized it to use with d3js. 
Hope this help you.

In D3

```
function midpoint (lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {

lat1= deg2rad(lat1);
lng1= deg2rad(lng1);
lat2= deg2rad(lat2);
lng2= deg2rad(lng2);

dlng = lng2 - lng1;
Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dlng);
By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dlng);
lat3 = Math.atan2( Math.sin(lat1)+Math.sin(lat2),
Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1)+Bx)*(Math.cos(lat1)+Bx) + By*By ));
lng3 = lng1 + Math.atan2(By, (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx));

   return (lat3*180)/Math.PI .' '. (lng3*180)/Math.PI;
}

function deg2rad (degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};
```

**Update 1**

If you try to draw curve line, you should create a path with coordination such as :

```
var lat1=53.507651,lng1=10.046997,lat2=52.234528,lng2=10.695190;


    var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({width:700 , height:600});
    svg.append("path").attr("d", function (d) {
      var dC="M "+lat1+","+lng1+ " A " + midpoint (lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
         + " 0 1,0 " +lat2 +" , "+lng2 +"Z";
        return dC;

    })
    .style("fill","none").style("stroke" ,"steelblue");
```

You need to create your curve line as you want in d3.
JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/Lbxbf1m2/4/).

Comment: Thanks. Does this account for a slight curve or just draw a straight line?

Comment: I update my answer to draw curve line, but I think the @potatopeelings answer is very cool.

Comment: Thanks, have you tested this to make sure it draws the curved line? Do you have a working example (fiddle, codepen etc)? Thanks for all the help and great answer too

Comment: I update my answer and add jsfiddle link. sorry I could not load any map to jsfiddle but the coordinate are get from google map.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [geo-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geo-lib)
and works