# Get latitude and longitude points along a line between two points, by percentage

Tags: javascript, math, leaflet, latitude-longitude, geo

In the image below, you can see that there 3 lines drawn from one point (the black circle) to its 3 related points ().

**IMAGE**

[image]

**QUESTION**

How to calculate latitude and longitude point between points along each line, using a percentage of the distance between the two points?

For example, if I wanted to get the position to be able to draw additional circles along each line with a 20% difference?

**WHAT CODE I HAVE NOW**

```
var data = [
  { "coords" : [ 53.409045, -2.985406 ]},
  { "coords" : [ 53.408747, -2.982862 ]},
  { "coords" : [ 53.407630, -2.984136 ]},
  { "coords" : [ 53.407142, -2.986931 ]}
];


var pointA = new L.LatLng(53.409045, -2.985406);
var pointB; 

data.forEach(function(d) {
  pointB = new L.LatLng(d.coords[0], d.coords[1]);
  L.polyline([pointA, pointB]).addTo(map);
  L.circle([d.coords[0], d.coords[1]], 10).addTo(map);
});
```

The only things the code above is doing is drawing a circle for each point and a line from the main circle (pointA) to the other circles (pointB)

I pretty much need to know how to calculate multiple coordinates, by percentage of distance, between the pointA and and its related points.

I need to make sure all green circle are the same distance from the center circle

**CODEPEN TO TEST WITH**

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNqOOX)

**EDIT - IMAGES OF WHAT i HAVE SO FAR USING THE CORRECT ANSWER BELOW**

[image]
[image]

Comment: For your searching work, the points you're looking for are known as "waypoints" along a Great Circle Route.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks. I know how to get the distance. between the two points now. So I now need to figure out how to get the "waypoint" based on a percentage of the distance? Do you know of any links to help with the calculation for this?

Comment: Here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation#Finding_way-points  Notice linear interpolation will work acceptably well if you're tracing a line from your apartment to the local supermarket, but terribly if you're going from New York to New Delhi.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for the advice and link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning : this works on a linear coordinates. As Ollie Jones mentioned, while this is a reasonable approximation for short distances (or for certain cases depending on your projection), this won't work for long distance or if you want a very accurate *point at percent***

The function you are looking for is pointAtPercent. Red is the start point (your center circle) and green the end point (your end circles)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

function drawPoint(color, point) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawLine(point1, point2) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray';
    ctx.setLineDash([5, 5]);    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
    ctx.stroke();    
}


function pointAtPercent(p0, p1, percent) {
    drawPoint('red', p0);
    drawPoint('green', p1);
    drawLine(p0, p1);

    var x;
    if (p0.x !== p1.x)
        x = p0.x + percent * (p1.x - p0.x);
    else
        x = p0.x;

    var y;
    if (p0.y !== p1.y)
        y = p0.y + percent * (p1.y - p0.y);
    else
        y = p0.y;

    var p = {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
    drawPoint('blue', p);

    return p;
}


pointAtPercent({ x: 50, y: 25 }, { x: 200, y: 300 }, 0.2)
pointAtPercent({ x: 150, y: 25 }, { x: 300, y: 100 }, 0.6)
pointAtPercent({ x: 650, y: 300 }, { x: 100, y: 400 }, 0.4)
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/goev47aL/

Comment: @Alan - Hope you got the other one (gap between 2 arc midpoints must be same irrespective of the distance between points) working with the fiddle in the chat? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I will have a try at implementing it my end now. I sed the example provided in the answer above, however it seems to be off a little, maybe my bearing calculation is off? Yes the other one is now fine.

Comment: Thanks I will do. I don't think I got the problem working where I had to make sure the curved lines gap was the same

Comment: This one? jsfiddle.net/gm7jx81a

Comment: Yes, weirdly, when I plug my values in they are not the same, like your fiddle ones are. I assume this is something my end causing it. Do you have any links that you regularly use for geo/coordinates math based equations?

Comment: Instead of getting the position for a point a certain percentage distance away from p0. can we get the point for a specific distance away from p0?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com would probably have good stuff on geo as well. For the point at specific distance it should be easy enough to calculate the % based on the specific distance and the total distance between the points and then use the above code. Cheers!

Comment: Any joy for: "Instead of getting the position for a point a certain percentage distance away from p0. can we get the point for a specific distance away from p0? " For example, get the point along the line for 10m away from p0

Comment: Bearing seems to be off a little using: `var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();`

Comment: I know the question asked for a percentage based distance between p0 and P1. Your answers works great for percentage. How could I change your solution so that it gives me a specific distance from p0 to p1? Say 20meters away from p0?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if I have `latitude` and `longitude` values for `x` and `y` of `pointAtDistance()`. For example `
pointAtDistance({ x: 53.407371, y: -2.982342 }, { x: 53.40763, y: -2.984136 }, 70)`? The value of `d` is much smaller when using latitude and longitude values.

Comment: The solution there is for cartesion coordinates... if you have a latitude / longitude, you need to first project it onto a Cartesian scale using whichever projection seems appropriate. Check out what we did in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428016/calculate-the-mid-point-of-latitude-and-longitude-co-ordinates (we converted before we did the calculation and reversed it before we printed the output)

Comment: Thanks, I can do the cartesian conversion now, but it still seems based on `%` of `p0` and `p1`

Comment: I will try to get my data etc into a fiddle. Currently, your method seems to still draw my point based on a percentage. I want to circle to always be drawn, say 20meters, px or any other unti away from p0

Comment: There is a lot of data behind what code so the fiddle may take a while to create. In the mean time I have added some images to the original post showing what is happening when drawing the new circles. They are the light green ones. It seems they are based on a percentage of the distance of the line they are related to

Comment: Er. I'm pretty sure it's not percentage in the above fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cztchLgp/) because if it were all the blue dots would be right in the center of the lines (since we've given the 3rd parameter as 50 in all 3 calls)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84988/discussion-between-alan-and-potatopeelings).

Comment: I was thinking that. Maybe i am doing something wrong. When I pass the new values into pointAtPercent(), the lines of code: `x = p0.x + percent * (p1.x - p0.x);` and `y = p0.y + percent * (p1.y - p0.y);` create value based on a percentage?

Answer (score 8):

See this page for your different equations. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

1. Get distance and bearing from origin to destination.
2. Convert percentage to distance in the applicable units.
3. Use bearing from #1, distance from #2 and origin to get resulting location

   ```
   function destination(lat, lon, bearing, distance) {
       var R = 6378.1, lat, lon, latDest, lonDest;

       // convert to radians
       lat = lat * (Math.PI / 180);
       lon = lon * (Math.PI / 180);
       bearing = bearing * (Math.PI / 180);

       latDest = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat) * Math.cos(distance / R) +
           Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(distance / R) * Math.cos(bearing));

       lonDest = lon + Math.atan2(Math.sin(bearing) * Math.sin(distance / R) * Math.cos(lat),
               Math.cos(distance / R) - Math.sin(lat) * Math.sin(latDest));

       return [latDest * (180 / Math.PI), lonDest * (180 / Math.PI)];
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you tested this on the codepen provided? I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to work, but is off by a small amount. Maybe a bearing calculation is off?

Comment: Hi, bearing seems to off a little using L `var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();`