# Latitude and Longitude Mid Point Calculation based on timing

Tags: php, algorithm, google-maps, math, latitude-longitude

Example:- Car A starting from position AA(LatA,LonA) at 10:00 AM and moving toward Position BB.

Similarly Car B starting from position BB(LatB,LonB) at 11:00 AM (Delay by one hour) and moving toward position BB.

I need to find at what time they will be meeting each other and I need to find the meeting point (LatM,LonM).

The Latitude and Longitude is stored in MySQL database hence I need to perform this things in backend and am supposed to show only the result in frontend. I am using PHP and I have calculated the distance between the two points (in miles).

How do I find the meeting latitude and longitude, store it in the database and later send this as a response to android device?

**UPDATE**

So at last I have done something by my own and I think this will work, but as we are talking about the web technologies server might respond slowly as this will take lots of execution time.

What am doing now is I am storing Encoded Polyline,Distance and Duration using Javascript in google Maps.

So when am calculating midpoint lat and lng,

First am getting the time delay, and total time taken to reach from one place to another.

In loop:- eq total time taken is 3 hours to reach from one point to another.

and delay is one hour from Car B.

The mid point will be exactly at 1.5 hours of time

So now for each decoded polyline steps I will add the duration until it reaches the mid point. Once it does am checking for the delay and according to that am making it to move forward again and taking the lat lng for that meeting point.

I might have made my page slow but am happy that I have achieved this.

Please suggest if there is any better idea.

Comment: I am sure I have seen this question before, yesterday.

Comment: please provide me the link ... wish i could get my solution there

Comment: i have been searching and trying for this from past two days.

Comment: Sounds like some coursework to me

Comment: The problem here is that lat/lon isn't enough. You need a road map with average speeds or, at a minimum, the speed limit of each road. You will need traffic lights and stop signs. Then, you need to calculate the best route for each to take, based on travel time data, so you can figure out when they will meet.

Comment: coursework? i have been searching for formulas and algorithm for past twp days and am unable to solve this issue. So if you know some thing which might solve mine or somebody else in future then you can help me out. though am not forcing you to search and do coursework. Thanks anyway @RiggsFolly

Comment: Found this, but it is not all you need I dont think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428016/calculate-the-mid-point-of-latitude-and-longitude-co-ordinates/31431920#31431920 but it might move you in the right direction

Comment: @kainaw thanx. I have the speed as we are assuming 90 miles/hour.
This whole thing is an assumption for future. Location need not be accurate but yes somewhere nearer to the exact mid location.

Comment: Try clicking on the "latitude-longitude" tag it will take you to all questions in that section. You may be able to find a question a bit similiar to yours with an answer attached

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanx. But  i think i have already tried this logic. They are not using time here and in my scenario the mid point will depend on the time  both car started

Comment: Thanx once again @RiggsFolly will do that

Comment: @RiggsFolly i cant find any question which is related to this thing.

Comment: @todownvoter :- Seems someone who is very intelligent and can solve this question with just one blink and thinks this question is just waste of time. But seems never wants to share what he knows. Good

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was wrong about the other question being similiar or maybe it got deleted _Not your downvoter_

Comment: Not an issue @RiggsFolly thanx for your help :-) .  Will try to figure it out by myself and soon will be answering this one by my own.

Comment: Yes adding an answer to this question would be a great idea.

Comment: Sure i will find the solution as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: Alright, you've got your distance, your car speeds (identical, I assume), and your delay. Your starting point would be the middle point between AA and BB, and then you shift it by one hour's worth of distance towards BB, right? Is that what you're asking, or something related to handling all this in PHP or MySQL, or Android?

Comment: @Twon-ha I think you are getting slightly wrong. Starting point is AA and ending point is BB for car A and vice versa for car B.
They are running toward each other. Now i need to find at what position(Latitude and Longitude) are they going to meet each other.
This whole thing is done in PHP.
Remember Car B is starting with some delay(1 hour in my situation)

Comment: Right, but if they start at the same time, they'll meet at the exact mid-point between AA and BB. If one of the cars has a head start of one hour on the other one, you just need to add one hour's worth of distance for the car that left from AA, and shift the meeting point accordingly. I really don't see how this is going to be useful in any real-world app though, are you sure this isn't a school assignment?

Comment: @Twon-ha :-D Seriously not. this is not a school Assignment. One of our client who really wants me to do thins in his application to save time and money for his work. 
So is it possible to shift latitude and longitude by one hour/delayed time?

Comment: View the distance between the two as a line. Say it's 200 km long. at 100 km would be the meeting point if they leave at the same time. If the cars are going at 80 km/h you just add 80 (km/hour) * 1 (hour) = 80km to the middle point, giving you 180 km from AA, and 20 km from BB.

Comment: This is okay @Twon-ha but again as i said i need latitude and longitude of that meeting position.
Like if i have Latitude and Longitude , now who could i shift this by an hour?is it possible

Comment: This is really more of a math problem than a programming problem.  (@Twon-ha Add first, then divide: they meet 140km from AA.)

Comment: Please check the updated one. I have found solution, @Twon-ha

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry, Everything has maths. And we are talking about coding so why not. Am working on PHP i think thats good enough :-) Please see my Updated one and tell me if there is any better idea to achieve this.

Comment: @Teepeemm woops, you're right. 80 + (200 - 80)/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using Polyline generated by google maps using javascript.
I have stored all the polyline in db and compared with other polyline in loop.
I know this will be slow in some situations but i had no other options
Thank you everyone